# How to enable/disable a hook with theme options

Tags: actions, theme-options

I am trying to use this function to add maintenance mode feature by adding this in my theme's functions.php and I am trying to use my theme options to enable/disable it.

I realized when i check/uncheck this via theme options page, it doesnt work. My guess is, once the action is added, it cannot be disabled. I tried to add elseif condition with remove_action for the same hook, but that didn't work either..

```
        function mytheme_under_construction(){

            // if user is logged in, don't show the construction page
            if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                return;
            }
            $protocol = $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"];
            if ( 'HTTP/1.1' != $protocol && 'HTTP/1.0' != $protocol )
                $protocol = 'HTTP/1.0';
            // 503 is recommended :  http://bit.ly/YdGkXl
            header( "$protocol 503 Service Unavailable", true, 503 );
            // or header( "$protocol 200 Ok", true, 200 );
            header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
            // adjust the Retry-After value (in seconds)
            header( 'Retry-After: 3600' );

        ?>
        <?php get_template_part('maintanance'); ?>
        <?php

            die();      
        }

global $mytheme;
if(!empty($mytheme['offline_id'])){
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'amytheme_under_construction' );
}
```

The onyl way it works is when I direclty add/remove the ! from this line:

```
if(!empty($mytheme['offline_id'])){
```

Can anyone help me with the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add `var_dump($mytheme)` just after `global $mytheme`? What does it output? Also show us, pls, how do you register and set your options.

Comment: Just fixed my issue, by running the theme options condition inside the function. Thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually all I had to do is, run theme options inside the function, like this:

```
        function mytheme_under_construction(){
        global $mytheme;
        if(!empty($mytheme['offline_id'])){
            // if user is logged in, don't show the construction page
            if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                return;
            }
            $protocol = $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"];
            if ( 'HTTP/1.1' != $protocol && 'HTTP/1.0' != $protocol )
                $protocol = 'HTTP/1.0';
            // 503 is recommended :  http://bit.ly/YdGkXl
            header( "$protocol 503 Service Unavailable", true, 503 );
            // or header( "$protocol 200 Ok", true, 200 );
            header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
            // adjust the Retry-After value (in seconds)
            header( 'Retry-After: 3600' );

        ?>
        <?php get_template_part('maintanance'); ?>
        <?php

            die();      
        }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'amytheme_under_construction' );
```